# Реализовать алгоритм исключения дубликатов

Tags: c

Мне надо реализовать алгоритм исключения дубликатов из массива (без создания нового). Смотрел реализацию функции [std::unique](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) в плюсах.

```
int* unique(int* first, int* last) {
    if (first == last)
        return last;

    int* result = first;

    while (++first != last) {
        if (*result != *first) {
            *(++result) = *first;
        }
    }

    return ++result;
}
```

Переделал - убрал шаблоны. Вроде бы даже и работает, но я этим пользоваться не могу... Слишком неудобно применять. Хочу переделать в нормальный вариант - хотя-бы с индексами вместо этой чертовой адресной арифметики.

```
typedef struct Array {
    int* data;
    int length;
} Array;

Array array_distinct(Array arr) {
  int index = 0;

  for (int i = 1; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
      if (arr.data[index] != arr.data[i]) {
          arr.data[++index] = arr.data[i];
      }
  }

  arr.length = index;
  return arr;
}

int main() {
  int input[] = { 1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 6 };

  Array a;
  a.data = input;
  a.length = sizeof(input) / sizeof(int);
  Array b = array_distinct(a);

  for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
      printf("%d\n", b.data[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Но что-то никак не выходит... Помогите исправить пожалуйста.

Comment: Структура данных, которая вам нужна, называется *ассоциативный массив*.

Comment: @0andriy, Во первых каким боком тут ассоциативные массивы? Это же набор пар ключ-значение. Где вы видите у меня такое? Во вторых вы знаете много реализаций ассоциативных массивов на чистом Си?

Comment: Самое непосредственное отношение это имеет, так как ключ считается с помощью простой хэш-функции, когда вы получаете ассоциативный массив, вы сразу видите дубликаты, не надо никаких дополнительных телодвижений. И вообще, программирование — это о структурах данных прежде всего, а потом уже о функциях (да, за исключением функциональных ЯП) и коде.

Comment: Реализаций полно, возьмите красно-чёрное дерево и CRC32, например.

Comment: Что вы предлагаете использовать за ключи, а что за значения? Я не особо понимаю как это вообще применимо к моему вопросу. Так или иначе мне уже не надо - все решили ниже.

Comment: Почитайте лучше про структуры данных, если вам интересно программирование как профессиональный навык. Дерево: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie Ассоциативный массив на Си: https://github.com/jimlawless/map_lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Array array_distinct(Array arr) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length - 1; )
    {
        if (arr.data[j] == arr.data[j+1])
        {
            for(int i = j+1; i < arr.length; ++i)
                arr.data[i-1] = arr.data[i];
            arr.length--;
        }
        else ++j;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Писано на коленке, но вроде должно работать...

Comment: Мне кажется не особо хорошо менять length по которому идет цикл внутри этого цикла.

Comment: Почему же? Это текущая длина массива. Вы удалили элемент? Надо соответственно обновить состояние массива - указать его новую длину.

Comment: **вроде должно работать...** - Этот алгоритм будет работать только на уже **отсортированном** массиве. TS нигде не сказал, что это так.

Comment: @Sergey Конечно :) Но он 1. привел как основу алгоритм `unique` - неужели он не прочитал о предусловиях его работы? и 2. Его пример данных отсортирован. Конечно, это могут быть и совпадения, но...

Comment: Да я в курсе что массив должен быть предварительно отсортирован.